# Android Animation for hightlight

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to learn how to do animation on Android. I want to use tween from my understanding via XML. I want to just highlight a text view, but I can't seem to find any simple examples that work, most seem to go for rotating. Anyone have an idea?

Also once I make the animation work does it block while the animation happens? Should I thread it if I am waiting for it to finish to run another event? I haven't been able to figure this out from reading the documentation. My java threading is very rusty.

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of examples available for tween animation for a particular widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animations thread themselves.
You won't be able to do this animation directly, because property animations are only available in Honeycomb. This animation is unnecessarily complicated because of the lack of animations. What you would have to do in order to accomplish this is to place the TextView in a FrameLayout. Create and LinearLayout with the highlight color you would like and Scale or Alpha animate that LinearLayout. If you would REALLY want to do this, I can show you.

Comment: From reading some documentation it seems more forward than this. I'm am confused by this response.

Comment: I did some reading and it appears you are correct, can you please show me how. I am new to this and so far don't like it.

Comment: Thanks, this and the above comment helped me figure this out. In the end I used a fade in the tween animation.

Comment: Glad to hear you've figured it out.